# All array value keys at [0] with simple html dom

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a Mirror site for Anime

```
file_get_contents($page);

$html->load_file($page);

$links = array();

foreach($html->find('iframe') as $element) 
{
    $links[] = $element;    
}

foreach ($links as $out) 
{
$links = preg_match('/(http:\/\/mp4upload.com).+?(html)/', $out, $matches);
unset($matches[1]);
unset($matches[2]);
    if($matches){                               
        $mirror_link = $matches[0];
```

This is my current code but every time I load it

The array shows up like this

```
Array ( [0] => LINK ) 
Array ( [0] => LINK  ) 
Array ( [0] => LINK  ) 
Array ( [0] => LINK )
```

Is it possible to limit this to only 1 link and remove the rest?

Comment: That moment when u ask a question and only get +rep xD

Comment: Stop to use this crappy API and learn DOMDocument and DOMXPath *(that are able to do the same thing better and faster)*.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `break` your loop when you find what you are looking for:

```
$mirror_link = [];

foreach ($links as $out) {
    ...

    if ($matches) {                               
        $mirror_link = $matches[0];

        break; // <-- Will prevent loop form iterating further.
        //break(2) will break current and parent loop
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but then i cant use the $mirror_link anywhere else it seems

Comment: @test42132132 You have to define `$mirror_link` somewhere before loop.

Comment: Did that still simular output that it doesnt get the imput from matches[0]